# Meteor Error on ubuntu. Exited with code: 1 => Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, meteor

I am new on Meteor and i just installed meteor on my ubuntu. Until then everything was fine. But after that whenever i wanted to create my first meteor app i got this problem

```
W20171106-22:15:32.531(1)? (STDERR) /home/shahin/firstApp/.meteor/local

/build/programs/server/boot.js:467
W20171106-22:15:32.532(1)? (STDERR) }).run();
W20171106-22:15:32.532(1)? (STDERR)    ^
W20171106-22:15:32.533(1)? (STDERR) 
W20171106-22:15:32.533(1)? (STDERR) Error: The babel-runtime npm package could not be found in your node_modules 
W20171106-22:15:32.533(1)? (STDERR) directory. Please run the following command to install it:
W20171106-22:15:32.534(1)? (STDERR) 
W20171106-22:15:32.534(1)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
W20171106-22:15:32.534(1)? (STDERR) 
W20171106-22:15:32.534(1)? (STDERR)     at babel-runtime.js (packages/babel-runtime.js:36:9)
W20171106-22:15:32.535(1)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:333:9)
W20171106-22:15:32.535(1)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:228:16)
W20171106-22:15:32.535(1)? (STDERR)     at packages/babel-runtime.js:155:15
W20171106-22:15:32.535(1)? (STDERR)     at packages/babel-runtime.js:166:3
W20171106-22:15:32.536(1)? (STDERR)     at infos.forEach.info (/home/shahin/firstApp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:414:13)
W20171106-22:15:32.536(1)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20171106-22:15:32.536(1)? (STDERR)     at /home/shahin/firstApp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:413:9
W20171106-22:15:32.536(1)? (STDERR)     at /home/shahin/firstApp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:463:5
W20171106-22:15:32.537(1)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/home/shahin/firstApp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

I have that problem when i wrote this command on my terminal

```
shahin@shahin-Inspiron-N5010:~$ cd firstApp
shahin@shahin-Inspiron-N5010:~/firstApp$ meteor -v
```

Will be glad if someone help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Looks like you haven't run `meteor npm install` yet. Meteor doesn't manage npm packages for you, so you'll need to run the command yourself.